# isdigit() returning false result?

Tags: c

I'm always getting any numeric string with the length of 2 detected as non digital by using isdigit() function, this is the code:

```
void testdigi(){
    char* tt="22";
    char* tt2= "222222222";
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tt)/sizeof(char);i++)
        if (!isdigit(tt[i])) printf("22 not digital\n");
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tt2)/sizeof(char);i++)
        if (!isdigit(tt2[i])) printf("222222222 not digital\n");
}
```

I don't know why 22 is not detected as digital,
so what's wrong? and how to resolve the problem?
thanks.

Comment: Use `strlen()`, not `sizeof()`. `sizeof(tt)` is `sizeof(char *)` which is likely either 4 or 8 (depends on your platform).

Comment: `sizeof(tt)` size of pointer( to char).

Comment: You are overstepping the first array.

Comment: you are right, I replaced sizeof() with strlen() and it works now, thanks.

Comment: No matter the bit size of `char`, `sizeof(char)` will *always* return `1` as per the C specification. The divisions are not needed in this case.

Comment: There is **no** need to mark titles as solved on SO. Just mark the answer of your choice by clicking it's check mark and SO knows this issues is "solved".

Comment: Also, you seem to mix your vocabulary. If something is said to be "digital", it means that the something can have either of two states: on or off. The words "digit" (as in a digit in a number, or a digit on a hand (finger)) and "digital" mean different things.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you think that `sizeof` on a pointer give the size of what it points to. Hint: It gives you the size of *the pointer* (which is typically 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine).

Either use `strlen` to get the length of strings, or use arrays instead of pointers.

Besides, even if you use pointers, you have to remember that they point to *constant* strings, so the correct definition would be e.g.

```
const char *tt = "22";
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you should have modified your code like this:

```
void testdigi(){
    char* tt="22";
    char* tt2= "222222222";
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tt)/sizeof(char);i++)
        if (!isdigit(tt[i])) printf("22 not digital\n");
        else printf("22 is digital\n");
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tt2)/sizeof(char);i++)
        if (!isdigit(tt2[i])) printf("222222222 not digital\n");
        else printf("222222222 is digital\n");
}
```

And you might have been enlighted of what is wrong beforehand.